# How to move position of a checkboxlist on webforms c#/HTML

Tags: c#, html, checkboxlist

Im trying to place a checkbox list on a specific location.
[what i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fy9JF.png)

I Need that checkbox list to be align on the left, but i cant move it
this is what i have
[what i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4w5Xx.png)

Hope u can help me!

this is the HTML code

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblAccesorios" runat="server" TextAlign="Right">              
            <asp:ListItem Value="2000,50">Monitor LCD</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="550,50">HD 500 GB</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1200">Grabador DVD</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

edit
this is the whole HTML code

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Ejercicio5.aspx.cs" Inherits="Tp2Prog.Ejercicio5" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            text-align: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="auto-style1">
            <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="X-Large" Text="Elija su configuración"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <br />
<strong>Seleccione cantidad de memoria&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Seleccione accesorios</strong><br />

            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRam" runat="server" Height="21px" Width="65px">
                <asp:ListItem Value="200">2 GB</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="375">4 GB</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="500">6 GB</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
&nbsp;
            <br />

            <br />
            <br />
            &nbsp;<asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblAccesorios" runat="server">              
                <asp:ListItem Value="2000,50">Monitor LCD</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="550,50">HD 500 GB</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="1200">Grabador DVD</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:CheckBoxList>
            <br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
   
            <div>
                </div>
            <br />
 
            <br />
           
            <asp:Button ID="btnPrecio" runat="server" OnClick="btnPrecio_Click" Text="Calcular Precio"/>
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="lblPrecio" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="XX-Large"></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: put all your html in the question

Comment: You should look at the HTML (and CSS, if it uses that) of the page that is laid out as you want and copy that. Also, the page appearance in the designer might not be the same as in the final page as displayed in a browser.

Comment: I have to do it as homework, and i can only use HTML (very little) and C#. Im not allowed to use Css yet.